# Laravel and AWS PHP SDK - Unable to delete a local file after it was uploaded to S3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5.1

I am trying to delete a file from a local directory right after I have uploaded it to AWS S3. When I run it on Vagrant I get an error = Text-file:busy, and when I run it on xampp I get the error :permission denied. For some reason the AWS S3 PutObject method is not releasing the file handle. I have tried to unset the s3 object but that didn't work.

Here is the code:

```
    $tempName = public_path().'/path/to/file'

    //Initialize AWS
    $s3 = AWS::createClient('s3');


    //Upload image to AWS

    try {
        $reponse = $s3->putObject(array(
            'Bucket'       => 'zotamoda',
            'Key'          => $productImage->image_folder."/".$productImage->image_name,
            'SourceFile'   => $tempName,
            'ACL'          => 'public-read',
        ));
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        // The AWS error code (e.g., )
        echo $e->getAwsErrorCode() . "\n";
        // The bucket couldn't be created
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }


    //Delete image from temporary location
    unlink($tempName);
```

Comment: It is very OS dependant, php has little control on the behaviour. Even if you make it work in your development box it does not mean it will work when you deploy. You better off looking to use temp file or use cron job to remove them from time to time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put($productImage->image_folder."/".$productImage->image_name, file_get_contents($tempName), 'public');
unlink($tempName);
```

or, assuming that `$tempName` is relative to your project root:

```
Storage::disk('local')->delete($tempName)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try calling:

```
gc_collect_cycles();
```

before deleting the file